# AssertionError: expected [Function] to equal 'EthSwap Instant Exchange'

Tags: reactjs, truffle

I am doing a tutorial on the web and I ran into an error while trying to run a truffle test. I am not sure where I am going wrong or what to do in this event.

Code:

```
contract('EthSwap', (accounts) => {
    
    describe('EthSwap deployment', async () => {
        it('contract has a name', async () => {
            let ethSwap = await EthSwap.new()
            const name = await ethSwap.name
            assert.equal(name, 'EthSwap Instant Exchange')
        })
    })
    
})
```

This is the error I am getting when I run the test:

> AssertionError: expected [Function] to equal 'EthSwap Instant Exchange'

Any help is greatly appreciated. This may be a very silly question but I am new at this. Thanks. Just a note that I went much further than this stage before and have gotten this code to work before in different scenarios before I ran into a big problem where things became so complicated that I decided to roll back. Now I am having problems that I didn't encounter before at this simple stage in the project.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a problem here in this file. It is problem in your EthSwap.sol file wherein the string variable name you have written

incorrect - **"EthSwap instant Exchange"**

correct -  **"EthSwap Instant Exchange"**

I think it will help you.